# password editText in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

can someone show me a code to realise that second EditText of the password

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:placeholderText="Password"
            app:expandedHintEnabled="false"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
             />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Use `app:expandedHintEnabled="false"` to display the placeholder also when the text field is empty.

Comment: hey, thnx for the help sir, this does quite the job, the only thing that remains is that the hint is not placed like the hint in the edittext view, also i ried to modify the size of the hint but it didn't work, here is the result https://drive.google.com/file/d/10GhF1vGHsvr7vdKEAFdQuDb56eu7cA85/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm so glad I stumbled on this. I've been looking for the right flag (`app:expandedHintEnabled`) to get my placeholder text to show up when not focused for like two days, haha. I couldn't find that anywhere! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

This is using material design:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/login_pwd"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_lock">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etLoginClave"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: hey, thank you sir for the help, the result is the same as the first comment, i added a link to a screenshot there

Comment: Can you post the edittext filled with some text so we can see what do you expect to see? I'm kinda lost what you exactly want